# Google App Script - What Can Be Stored in Array?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried to push a value called "ticker" into a Google App Script Array:

```
ticker = name_cell.offset(0, i).getDisplayValue();
```

i.e. a Range object with two methods behind, which supposedly return a value. I think.

As I push such tickers into an Array, may I know whether I am actually pushing a value (which is what I wanted to do) or am I pushing the whole bulk of object.method.method syntax into the Array (which I suspected so)?

I am asking this because I suspect it may be the later case and problem occurs. In array output I was given undefined as array values, even when I know the value being hold in ticker is correct.

May I know what I should do in such a case?

Code As Provided in Comment Below:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("something"); 
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PASTEVALUE") 
 var crossup = []; 
 var i; 
 var name_cell; 
 var cross_up_cell; 
 cross_up_cell = sheet.getRange(2, 1); 
 for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) 
 { 
    var ticker; 
    var value1; 
    ticker = name_cell.offset(0, i).getDisplayValue();//name_cell undefined 
    value1 = cross_up_cell.offset(0, i).getDisplayValue(); 
    if (value1=="YES") 
    {
        crossup.push(ticker)};//extraneous closing bracket here 
     }
```

Comment: Arrays can contain values, strings, arrays and objects and possibly things I don't even know about.

Answer (score 1):

getDisplayValue is a single value. Not an array. This is the documentations description. `getDisplayValue() String  Returns the displayed value of the top-left cell in the range.`

[Here's the link.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: Hello Cooper,
Yes I know it SHOULD be a value, and that's exactly my problem..., as I push ticker = name_cell.offset(0, i).getDisplayValue() into an array, whatever, say, ticks[], and output its values, it will simply give undefined. If it is a value then why is that...?

Comment: Hello Cooper,
Please see below:

'code'
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("something");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("PASTEVALUE")
var crossup = [];
var i;
var name_cell;
var cross_up_cell;
cross_up_cell = sheet.getRange(2, 1);
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
var ticker;
var value1;
ticker = name_cell.offset(0, i).getDisplayValue();
value1 = cross_up_cell.offset(0, i).getDisplayValue();
if (value1=="YES") {crossup.push(ticker)};
}
'code'

Comment: name_cell is undefined.